# How to limit max http POST Size on specific route - Spring web-flux [Project-Reactor]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty, project-reactor

I utilize the `server.jetty.max-http-form-post-size` setting to restrict the size of HTTP POST requests. However, this configuration does not allow me to set specific limits for individual routes. Is there a way to impose limitations on each route with varying sizes? Furthermore, does the max-http-form-post-size setting only limit the payload size or does it also affect limiting network bandwidth ? I would appreciate it if someone could provide an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create HandlerFilterFunction to set the maximum request size for a specific route as follow:

```
    public class MaxRequestSizeFilter implements HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {

    private final long maxRequestSize;

    public MaxRequestSizeFilter(long maxRequestSize) {
        this.maxRequestSize = maxRequestSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> filter(ServerRequest request, HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> next) {
        // Set the max request size for the request
        request.exchange().getRequest().setMaxInMemorySize((int) maxRequestSize);

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

then apply the above to specific routes in your application as follow:

```
    @Configuration
    public class RouteConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
            .POST("/route1", requestHandler::handleRoute1)
            .filter(new MaxRequestSizeFilter(1024 * 1024)) // Set max size to 1MB for route1
            .POST("/route2", requestHandler::handleRoute2)
            .filter(new MaxRequestSizeFilter(2048 * 1024)) // Set max size to 2MB for route2
            .build();
    }
    
}
```